# Tiling Theano tensor

Tags: python, theano

I have two tensors A and B where the first one has size (500,10) and the second has size (500). I want to find A / B.
I am using regular / operator and it Theano compiler says that they should be the same size.
Then I tried using tensor.tile on B to make it the same size as A. It has three parameters(x, reps, ndim). I tried different values and I am limited to these constraints:
x.ndim = len(reps) and ndim = len(reps)
Then having these constraints how can I tile the array to a matrix?! Is this a bug in Theano?

Answer (score 1):

You can just broadcast it, and there are several ways to do it. Take the following example

```
import numpy as np
A = np.arange(1., 5001., 1.).reshape(500, 10)
B = np.arange(1., 501., 1.)

import theano
As = theano.shared(A)
Bs = theano.shared(B)
```

The failsafe way of doing this is adding an appropriate axis

```
AoverB = A / B[:, np.newaxis]
AoverBalso = A / B.reshape((-1, 1))
AsoverBs = As / Bs.reshape((-1, 1))
```

Another way is to exploit the fact that there is implicit broadcasting to pad the first axes if they are missing

```
AoverBT = A.T / B.T   # no axis was added here
AsoverBsT = As.T / Bs.T
```

In order to show that all these calculate the same thing, we use `numpy.testing`

```
from numpy.testing import assert_array_equal
assert_array_equal(AoverB, AoverBalso)
assert_array_equal(AoverB, AsoverBs.eval())
assert_array_equal(AoverB, AoverBT.T)
assert_array_equal(AoverB, AsoverBsT.T.eval())
```